# Why does the SonarQube plugin for Eclipse use the "project name" instead of the "artifactID" to associate Maven projects with a SonarQube server?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, sonarqube

For Maven multi-module projects, I have noticed that the plugin does the module association using ***the name of its directory inside the workspace***, rather than using ***the artifactID contained inside the POM***. Because of this, if I change the name of the project to anything else, I cannot longer run successful incremental analyses. How can I fix this (undesired) behaviour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once your Eclipse project is associated to a remote SonarQube project, changing its name should have no impact (association is a dedicated metadata).

By default when you try to associate an Eclipse project we use the project name to do the search. This is because we want to be independent from Maven and support any Eclipse project.

Using the SonarQube m2e connector may help since it will automatically try to associate your Maven project with a remote project having the key `<groupId>:<artifactId>` which is the default key for a Maven project.

Comment: You are totally right. Thing is: Eclipse somehow "forgot" the association I had made before renaming a project, and that led me to erroneously believe that the plugin depended upon the project name. Thanks for the clarification. Lesson learned: Just make sure the association is still there.